# Agregar diferente links desde un enlace

Tags: javascript, html, css

tengo la siguiente pagina, tiene un div `.proyectos` con 6 divs adentro con la clase `contenedor-modal` y un `<div>` afuera del div `proyectos`, con la clase `.modal-container` que es un modal. Al dar click a cualquier div `contenedor-modal` se abre el modal que vendria siendo el div con la clase `modal-container` el cual muestra una imagen, un titulo y una imagen en forma de flecha la cual esta dentro de un enlace. Al hacer click en el `enlace` que es la imagen en forma de flecha, quiero que cada una me lleve a diferentes link. Por ejemplo: al dar click en el primer `div`me abre el modal `modal-container` y me muestra la imagen, el titulo y el enlace en forma de flecha, al dar click en el enlace quiero que me lleve a una pagina, `https://www.google.com/`, si doy click en el segundo div con la clase `contenedor-modal` me muestra el modal pero al dar click en el enlace que me lleve a `https://www.facebook.com/`, al dar click en el tercer enlace me lleve a `https://es.stackoverflow.com/` y asi sucesivamente, que cada enlace me lleve a diferentes paginas, como lo haria?

```js
// Selecciona todas las secciones
let imagenes = document.querySelectorAll('.contenedor-modal .imagen');
// Selecciona capa negra - Modal
let modalContainer = document.querySelector('#modal-container');
// Selecciona la ventana modal y botón cerrar
let modal = document.querySelector('.modal');
let cerrar = modal.querySelector('.close');
let modalTexto = modal.querySelector('.modal-textos');

// Asignar evento a imágenes
imagenes.forEach(imagen => imagen.addEventListener('click', abrirModal));
cerrar.addEventListener('click', cerrarModal);

// Abrir modal
function abrirModal(e) {
    modalContainer.classList.add('mostrar');
    modal.classList.remove('modal-close');

    // Obteener el contenedor que recibió link
    let imagen = e.target.closest('.imagen');
    console.log(imagen)

    //Obtener la imagen que esta dentro del contenedor imagen(class='imagen')
    let imagenModal = imagen.querySelector('.img-modal');
    console.log(imagenModal)

    //Obtener la imagen que esta dentro del contenedor #modal-container
    let imagenContainer = modalContainer.querySelector('.img-container')
    console.log(imagenContainer)

    //Cambiar el src(.img-modal) imagen del container por la imagen del modal(imagenModal)
    imagenContainer.src = imagenModal.src;

    // Obtener texto del elemento que recibió clic
    let titulo = imagen.querySelector('.capa p');

    // Cambiar título de modal
    modalTexto.querySelector('h2').textContent = titulo.textContent;

    // Posición del elemento que recibió click
    let posicion = Array.from(imagenes).indexOf(imagen);

}

//Cerar modal desde la X
function cerrarModal() {
    setTimeout(()=> {
        modalContainer.classList.remove('mostrar');
    }, 700);
    modal.classList.add('modal-close');
}

// Cerrar modal desde cualquier parte negra del DOM
document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if(e.target == modalContainer){
        cerrarModal();
    }
});
```

```css
section{
    width: 100%;

    margin-top: 90px;
}

section .proyectos{
    width: 90%;
    height: 600px;
    margin: 100px auto 200px auto;
}

section  h1{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 29px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 300;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

section  h1::before{
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ffffff, #f6e4f9, #fec5e2, #ffa5b6, #ff8b7b, #ff8b7b, #ff8b7b, #ff8b7b, #ffa5b6, #fec5e2, #f6e4f9, #ffffff);

}

/** ESTILOS MODAL - HOVER **/
section .proyectos{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}


section .proyectos .contenedor-modal{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

section .proyectos .contenedor-modal .contenedor{
    width: 370px;

}

section .proyectos .contenedor-modal .contenedor .imagen{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;/**OCULTA LOS ELEMENTOS  QUE SOBRESALE DE UN DIV**/
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 20px;
    cursor: zoom-in;
}

section .proyectos .contenedor-modal .contenedor .imagen img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    object-fit: cover;
    transition: all 500ms ease-out;
}

/** ESTILOS PARA EL EFECTO HOVER - LUPA**/
section .proyectos .contenedor-modal .contenedor .imagen .capa{
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.39);
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}

/** CAMBIAMOS EL TAMAÑO DE LA LUPA EN EL EFECTO HOVER**/
section .proyectos .contenedor-modal .contenedor .imagen:hover .capa{
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

section .proyectos .contenedor-modal .contenedor .imagen:hover .capa h3{
    margin-top: 220px;
    margin-bottom: ;
    color: #000;
}

section .proyectos .contenedor-modal .contenedor .imagen:hover img{
    transform: scale(1.2);
}

section .proyectos .contenedor-modal .contenedor .imagen .capa h3{

    margin-bottom:-20px;
    transition: all 500ms ease-out;
}

section .proyectos .contenedor-modal .contenedor .imagen .capa img{
    width: 220px;
    height: 220px;
    margin-top: -200px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

section .proyectos .contenedor-modal .contenedor .imagen .capa p{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-bottom: -100px;
}

section .proyectos .contenedor-modal .contenedor .imagen:hover .capa p{

}


/** ESTILOS DEL MODAL AL HACER CLICK EN LA IMAGEN AGRANDARLA **/

.modal-container{ 
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 0;
    position: fixed;/**DAR EL COLOR NEGRO TRANSPARENTE A TODA LA PAGINA AL DAR CLICK EN LA IMAGEN**/
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    transition:all 0.5s ease;
}
.modal-container.mostrar{ 
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    z-index: 1000;

}
.modal{
    width: 70%;
    height: 90%;
    background: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    position: relative;
    transition: transform 1s;
    transform: translateY(0%);
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.close{
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    line-height: 25px;
}


.modal-close{
    transform: translateY(-200%)
}


.modal > img{
    width: 95%;
    margin: 0px auto 0 auto;
}

.modal .modal-textos h2{
    font-size: 22px;
    margin-top: -45px;
}


.modal .modal-textos img{
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 600ms ease;
    display: block;
    margin: 15px auto 0 auto;
}

.modal .modal-textos img:hover{
    transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1.2);

}
```

```html
<section>
       <h1>Proyectos</h1>
        <div class="proyectos">

                <div class="contenedor-modal">
                   <div class="contenedor">
                       <div class="imagen uno" id="uno">
                           <img src="img/proyecto-uno.png" class="img-modal" >
                           <div class="capa">
                               <h3><img src="img/lupa2.png" ></h3>
                                <p>Pagina Web - Noticias</p>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
                </div>

                <div class="contenedor-modal">
                   <div class="contenedor">
                       <div class="imagen dos" id="dos">
                           <img src="img/proyecto-dos.png" class="img-modal" >
                           <div class="capa">
                               <h3><img src="img/lupa2.png" alt="" width='300px'></h3>
                                <p>Sueños En Realidad</p>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
                </div>

                <div class="contenedor-modal">
                   <div class="contenedor">
                       <div class="imagen tres" id="tres">
                           <img src="img/proyecto-tres.png" class="img-modal" >
                           <div class="capa">
                               <h3><img src="img/lupa2.png" alt=""></h3>
                                <p>Artistas Web</p>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
                </div>

                <div class="contenedor-modal">
                   <div class="contenedor">
                       <div class="imagen tres" id="tres">
                           <img src="img/proyecto-cinco.png" class="img-modal" >
                           <div class="capa">
                               <h3><img src="img/lupa2.png" alt=""></h3>
                                <p>Artistas Web</p>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
                </div>

                <div class="contenedor-modal">
                   <div class="contenedor">
                       <div class="imagen tres" id="tres">
                           <img src="img/proyecto-ocho.png" class="img-modal" >
                           <div class="capa">
                               <h3><img src="img/lupa2.png" alt=""></h3>
                                <p>Artistas Web</p>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
                </div>

                <div class="contenedor-modal">
                   <div class="contenedor">
                       <div class="imagen tres" id="tres">
                           <img src="img/proyecto-nueve.png" class="img-modal" >
                           <div class="capa">
                               <h3><img src="img/lupa2.png" alt=""></h3>
                                <p>Artistas Web</p>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
        </div> 

        <div class="modal-container" id="modal-container">
                <div class="modal modal-close">
                    <p class="close">X</p>
                    <img src="" class="img-container">
                    <div class="modal-textos">
                        <h2>Título modal</h2>
                        <a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">
                            <img src="img/brujula-direccional.svg" alt="">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta para ser más específico y detallado en lo que quieres que se muestre al abrir la modal y de dónde va a tomar los datos; también aclara a qué te refieres con _"me lleve a páginas diferentes"_.

Comment: Acabo de editar la pregunta, todo se muestra correctamente, solo quiero cambiar el link en el enlace(a) que esta dentro del .modal-textos. para que cada uno me lleve a un link diferente.(paginas que cree)

Comment: En el párrafo donde pones título puedes agregar un atributo `data-url="pagina.php"`, diferente para cada uno. Después, lo obtienes con `titulo.dataset.url` y asignas ese valor al `href` del enlace.

Comment: como lo obtengo.tendra que usar otro lenguaje,no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el párrafo donde tomas el título solo agrega el [atributo de datos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) `<p data-url="artistas.php">Artistas Web</p>` y puedes poner la URL que prefieras, ya sea dentro de tu proyecto u otro dominio.

```js
// Selecciona todas las secciones
let imagenes = document.querySelectorAll('.contenedor-modal .imagen');
// Selecciona capa negra - Modal
let modalContainer = document.querySelector('#modal-container');
// Selecciona la ventana modal y botón cerrar
let modal = document.querySelector('.modal');
let cerrar = modal.querySelector('.close');
let modalTexto = modal.querySelector('.modal-textos');

// Asignar evento a imágenes
imagenes.forEach(imagen => imagen.addEventListener('click', abrirModal));
cerrar.addEventListener('click', cerrarModal);

// Abrir modal
function abrirModal(e) {
    modalContainer.classList.add('mostrar');
    modal.classList.remove('modal-close');

    // Obteener el contenedor que recibió link
    let imagen = e.target.closest('.imagen');
    console.log(imagen)

    //Obtener la imagen que esta dentro del contenedor imagen(class='imagen')
    let imagenModal = imagen.querySelector('.img-modal');
    console.log(imagenModal)

    //Obtener la imagen que esta dentro del contenedor #modal-container
    let imagenContainer = modalContainer.querySelector('.img-container')
    console.log(imagenContainer)

    //Cambiar el src(.img-modal) imagen del container por la imagen del modal(imagenModal)
    imagenContainer.src = imagenModal.src;

    // Obtener texto del elemento que recibió clic
    let titulo = imagen.querySelector('.capa p');

    // Cambiar título de modal
    modalTexto.querySelector('h2').textContent = titulo.textContent;
    
    // Obtener URL desde el titulo
    let url = titulo.dataset.url;

    // Cambiar URL en modal
    modalTexto.querySelector('a').href = url;

}

//Cerar modal desde la X
function cerrarModal() {
    setTimeout(()=> {
        modalContainer.classList.remove('mostrar');
    }, 700);
    modal.classList.add('modal-close');
}

// Cerrar modal desde cualquier parte negra del DOM
document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if(e.target == modalContainer){
        cerrarModal();
    }
});
```

```css
section{
    width: 100%;

    margin-top: 90px;
}

section .proyectos{
    width: 90%;
    height: 600px;
    margin: 100px auto 200px auto;
}

section  h1{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 29px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 300;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

section  h1::before{
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ffffff, #f6e4f9, #fec5e2, #ffa5b6, #ff8b7b, #ff8b7b, #ff8b7b, #ff8b7b, #ffa5b6, #fec5e2, #f6e4f9, #ffffff);

}

/** ESTILOS MODAL - HOVER **/
section .proyectos{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}


section .proyectos .contenedor-modal{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

section .proyectos .contenedor-modal .contenedor{
    width: 370px;

}

section .proyectos .contenedor-modal .contenedor .imagen{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;/**OCULTA LOS ELEMENTOS  QUE SOBRESALE DE UN DIV**/
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 20px;
    cursor: zoom-in;
}

section .proyectos .contenedor-modal .contenedor .imagen img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    object-fit: cover;
    transition: all 500ms ease-out;
}

/** ESTILOS PARA EL EFECTO HOVER - LUPA**/
section .proyectos .contenedor-modal .contenedor .imagen .capa{
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.39);
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}

/** CAMBIAMOS EL TAMAÑO DE LA LUPA EN EL EFECTO HOVER**/
section .proyectos .contenedor-modal .contenedor .imagen:hover .capa{
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

section .proyectos .contenedor-modal .contenedor .imagen:hover .capa h3{
    margin-top: 220px;
    margin-bottom: ;
    color: #000;
}

section .proyectos .contenedor-modal .contenedor .imagen:hover img{
    transform: scale(1.2);
}

section .proyectos .contenedor-modal .contenedor .imagen .capa h3{

    margin-bottom:-20px;
    transition: all 500ms ease-out;
}

section .proyectos .contenedor-modal .contenedor .imagen .capa img{
    width: 220px;
    height: 220px;
    margin-top: -200px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

section .proyectos .contenedor-modal .contenedor .imagen .capa p{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-bottom: -100px;
}

section .proyectos .contenedor-modal .contenedor .imagen:hover .capa p{

}


/** ESTILOS DEL MODAL AL HACER CLICK EN LA IMAGEN AGRANDARLA **/

.modal-container{ 
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 0;
    position: fixed;/**DAR EL COLOR NEGRO TRANSPARENTE A TODA LA PAGINA AL DAR CLICK EN LA IMAGEN**/
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    transition:all 0.5s ease;
}
.modal-container.mostrar{ 
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    z-index: 1000;

}
.modal{
    width: 70%;
    height: 90%;
    background: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    position: relative;
    transition: transform 1s;
    transform: translateY(0%);
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.close{
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    line-height: 25px;
}


.modal-close{
    transform: translateY(-200%)
}


.modal > img{
    width: 95%;
    margin: 0px auto 0 auto;
}

.modal .modal-textos h2{
    font-size: 22px;
    margin-top: -45px;
}


.modal .modal-textos img{
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 600ms ease;
    display: block;
    margin: 15px auto 0 auto;
}

.modal .modal-textos img:hover{
    transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1.2);

}
```

```html
<section>
       <h1>Proyectos</h1>
        <div class="proyectos">

                <div class="contenedor-modal">
                   <div class="contenedor">
                       <div class="imagen uno" id="uno">
                           <img src="img/proyecto-uno.png" class="img-modal" >
                           <div class="capa">
                               <h3><img src="img/lupa2.png" ></h3>
                                <p data-url="noticias.php">Pagina Web - Noticias</p>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
                </div>

                <div class="contenedor-modal">
                   <div class="contenedor">
                       <div class="imagen dos" id="dos">
                           <img src="img/proyecto-dos.png" class="img-modal" >
                           <div class="capa">
                               <h3><img src="img/lupa2.png" alt="" width='300px'></h3>
                                <p data-url="realidad.php">Sueños En Realidad</p>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
                </div>

                <div class="contenedor-modal">
                   <div class="contenedor">
                       <div class="imagen tres" id="tres">
                           <img src="img/proyecto-tres.png" class="img-modal" >
                           <div class="capa">
                               <h3><img src="img/lupa2.png" alt=""></h3>
                                <p data-url="artistas.php">Artistas Web</p>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        <div class="modal-container" id="modal-container">
                <div class="modal modal-close">
                    <p class="close">X</p>
                    <img src="" class="img-container">
                    <div class="modal-textos">
                        <h2>Título modal</h2>
                        <a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">
                            <img src="img/brujula-direccional.svg" alt="">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Me funciono, Muchas Gracias